# ASIHTTPRequestDelegate methods not called in XPC service

Tags: objective-c, macos, asihttprequest, xpc

I am using the excellent ASIHTTPRequest inside an XPC service to fetch some data from the internet.

I am creating a simple request. However, for some reason, it's delegate functions are not called.
I have enabled ASIHTTPRequest's debugging log and so I see that the request does execute.
After digging in a bit,I found what might be the cause:

inside ASIHTTPRequest.m, in the end of the requestFinished method, there's a call:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reportFinished) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
```

the reportFinished method is the method that calls the delegate.
For some reason, it is never fired. If I replace this line with:

```
//[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reportFinished) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
[self reportFinished];
```

then the delegate is called. However, i assume it is called on the wrong thread as im running async requests.

What should I do to adapt the code so that it invokes the delegate's methods, without modifying the logic/threading of it?

Comment: are you sure that the main thread is not blocked? (that would explain why the method is not run on the main thread). is the UI responsive?

Comment: i don't think that it is blocked, there is no ui as it is a data provider xpc service. when i switch to gcd and dispatch to main thread it works as well

Comment: well, then you have found the solution: dispatch through GCD...

Comment: thought so too, though im having an EXC_BAD_ALLOCATION when the request is released. still have to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest converting the statement:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reportFinished) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
```

into this, which should be semantically equivalent:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    [self reportFinished];
} else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self reportFinished];
                   });
}
```

or simply this, which should also work:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self reportFinished];
                   });
```

Comment: eventually did the second one :)